# Node not found on laravel project

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, web-scraping, laravel-livewire

i've been trying to use a package called PuPHPeteer but i have a problem:

It seems like the package requires node to be used. https://github.com/zoonru/puphpeteer this is the package link. I installed it using the 2 commands posted on the page:

```
composer require zoon/puphpeteer
npm install github:zoonru/puphpeteer
```

I copied some of the code from the github page to test if it works:

```
 $puppeteer = new Puppeteer; ---> exception here
 $browser = $puppeteer->launch();
 $page = $browser->newPage();
```

But after i get to the first line of the code during execution i get this error:

*The command "node "C:\Users\Fran\Documents\GitHub\precios-project\app\vendor\zoon\rialto\src/node-process/serve.js" C:\Users\Fran\Documents\GitHub\precios-project\app\vendor\zoon\puphpeteer\src\PuppeteerConnectionDelegate.js "{""idle_timeout"":60,""log_node_console"":false,""log_browser_console"":false,""js_extra"":""""}"" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\Users\Fran\Documents\GitHub\precios-project\app\public Output: ================ Error Output: ================ "node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.*

Its in spanish because i use that lenguage in my computer but i think it is a typical "Node its not recognized error"

"node" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.* means "The term node is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program" i think.

[Error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0kok.png)

i only found solutions that talk about the path enviroment variable not being set correctly but i think mine is good.

[Capture of my path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oen4V.png)

Any ideas??

Tried to run PuPHPeteer in a laravel project.

Expected it to work.

Resulted in a node error.

Comment: You'll need node installed on the server.

Comment: From their Github page: "_Requirements and installation This package requires PHP >= 7.3 and Node >= 8._"

Comment: i already ran npm install in my folder and it keeps showing the same error.

Comment: What you are doing is trying to install JavaScript project packages. But first you have to install nodejs itself to your machine. Check [here](https://nodejs.org/en).

Comment: Node is installed on my pc. the location of the instalation is shown in the main question. im going to try using the repair node option to see if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing to Linux I no longer encountered the issue and it worked perfectly. It seems as if it was a problem setting up the development environment in Windows.